# Accessing a bean from class that implements WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, initialization

This is where I want to access the beans

```
 public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    
        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
         ....
       
         Show show = new Show(); 
         ....      
    }
}
```

This is where we manage our beans:

```
@Configuration
public class MyBeans {
     @Bean
     public Magic magic() {
        return new Magic();
     }
     @Bean
     public Magician magician() {
        return new magician();
     }

}
```

This is the Magician class:

```
 @Component 
 public class Magician {
   @Autowire
   Magic magic;     
   ....(other functions)
 }
```

This is the class for the show:

```
@Component 
 public class Magician {
   @Autowire
   Magician magician;     
   ....(other functions)
 }
```

I am looking for a way for my Show object to use the Magician bean created in the My beans class. It currently is not using the bean because I am using new to instantiate show and that means that it is not managed by spring. I have seen that there are implementations done using an AspectJ intercepter or using Application context. However when adding the following line: `ApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);` to my web initializer class I get an error indicating `No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?`I am not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: Can you share the class `Show`? It seems that you shared two times the class `Magician`

Comment: You cannot. As the `WebApplicationInitializer` is the place where everything is bootstrapped. Why would you need your `Show` in that class?